# How can I refresh my TableView in titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium

```
PopupFirstNameButton.addEventListener('click', FirstNameFunction);
function FirstNameFunction(){
    infoWin.close();
    dispalyFirstName = 'false';
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
           className:'sectionrow',
           height:50
    }); 
    row.add(FirstNameTextField);  
    tableview.height = row.height + tableview.height;
    SearchForPatientsButton.top = tableview.height + 80;

    tableview.insertRowBefore(0,row);

    FirstNameTextField.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //DetailedPatientSearchWindow.close();
        var FirstNameWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
          backgroundColor: '#1F561E',
          url:'FirstNameWindow.js'
      }).open();
    });
}


var PopupLastNameButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
    bottom:160,
    left:25,
    width:270,
    height:40,
    title:'Last Name',
    color:'#000',
    borderRadius:5,
    font:{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'}
});

PopupLastNameButton.addEventListener('click', LastNameFunction);

function LastNameFunction(obj){  
    infoWin.close();
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
           className:'sectionrow',
           height:50
    }); 
    row.add(LastNameTextField);  
    tableview.height = row.height + tableview.height;
    SearchForPatientsButton.top = tableview.height + 80;
    tableview.insertRowBefore(1,row);

    LastNameTextField.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //DetailedPatientSearchWindow.close();
        var FirstNameWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
          backgroundColor: '#1F561E',
          url:'LastNameWindow.js'
      }).open();
    });
}

var PopupGenderButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
    bottom:110,
    left:25,
    width:270,
    height:40,
    title:'Gender',
    color:'#000',
    borderRadius:5,
    font:{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'}
});

PopupGenderButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    infoWin.close();
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
           className:'sectionrow',
           height:50
    });
    row.add(GenderTextField);  
    tableview.height = row.height + tableview.height;
    SearchForPatientsButton.top = tableview.height + 80;
    tableview.insertRowBefore(2,row);
    GenderTextField.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var GenderWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
          url:'GenderWindow.js',
          backgroundColor:'#1F561E'
      }).open();
  });
});

var PopupDateOfBirthButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
    bottom:60,
    left:25,
    width:270,
    height:40,
    title:'Date of Birth',
    color:'#000',
    borderRadius:5,
    font:{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'}
});

PopupDateOfBirthButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    infoWin.close();
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
           className:'sectionrow',
           height:50
    });
    row.add(DateOfBirthTextField); 
    tableview.height = row.height + tableview.height; 
    SearchForPatientsButton.top = tableview.height + 80;
    tableview.insertRowBefore(3,row);
    DateOfBirthTextField.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var DateOfBirthWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
          url:'DateOfBirthWindow.js',
          backgroundColor:'#1F561E'
      }).open();
  });
});
```

you can see `tableview.insertRowBefore(3,row);` and similar... i am not sure how to loop the entire thing and get the value... There are such four

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableview.setData(tableview.data);
```

Comment: How can set the insertRowBefore(index value dyanmic rather than hardcoding it as 0 , 1, 2 etc )

Comment: loop and increment the index value

Comment: I just updated my entire code, i am not able to figure it out... thanks again

Comment: i think loop will not work, since the row is getting added on button click should we do something on count....