# Titanium refreshing TableView with new data

Tags: refresh, titanium, tableview

This is what I am trying to do:

```
_tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].imageId = tempImageId;     
_tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].image = tempImageUrl;  
Titanium.API.info("imageIdSelected:" + 
_tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].imageId + "imageSelected:" + 
_tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].image);
```

The update is done on the data, but it doesn't reflect in UI table, what is missing?

I even tried doing the below as per [How can I refresh my TableView in titanium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731461/how-can-i-refresh-my-tableview-in-titanium) & [How to resolve Titanium TableView display problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073876/how-to-resolve-titanium-tableview-display-problem), but it is not refreshing the UI table 
    _tableView.setData(_tableView.data); win.add(_tableView);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the only way to update/reload a Titanium.UI.TableView is to get a copy of the updated data (as per ones logic) and reset it in the TableView, using 'setData'. For my example, since the _tableView.data is getting updated (which could be seen through the logging statements), I could copy it using a javascript array copy function like;

```
var data2 =_tableView.data.slice(0); 
_tableView.setData(data2);
```

Although, with the above knowledge, I had restructure my code, so, I am not using this exact code, but a similar logic. But, overall, this way of updating the table doesn't seem very appealing, if there is any better way of handling this, please post, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `_tableView.data[0].rows` and then just `_tableView.data` when using `setData`?

Your `_tableView.data` should be an array of rows/sections. The [Ti.UI.tableView](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableView-object) object has the data property but the data should be structured as follows.

```
_tableView.data = [
    {title:"Row 1"},
    {title:"Row 2"}
];
```

What does the `.rows` accomplish for you when you are doing it that way, how are you using the `.rows`? I'm not positive but I think the `_tableView.data` is either no different or is invalid when trying to `setData`.

Comment: I have been trying out different things to get the code working. With my code above, the statement 'Titanium.API.info..' shows the data getting updated, but it doesn't update the _tableView.
How does one update a particular row/cell in a TableView and refresh the table in the UI? Can you provide an example of that?